# The delete function of firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to implement the delete function for my project. In which the function deletes the document by id. And after implementing that i am getting error. Which i am unable to fix.

I used this function to delete the doc.

```
function DeleteUser(){
    db.collection('rooms').doc(id).delete();
}
```

[image]
[image]

This is the link of the images of code and the error

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 1):

Once you call delete on the `/rooms/someId` document, your `onSnapshot` listener is getting fired with the new snapshot of this document (where it no longer exists).

You need to handle when `snapshot.exists` is `false` (recommended) or use `snapshot.get('name')` instead of `snapshot.data().name` and handle when the name is `undefined`.

Comment: are u talking about this.

Comment: db.collection("rooms").doc(id).collection("messages")
   .orderBy("timestamp", "desc").
   onSnapshot((snapshot)=>
    setMessages(snapshot.docs.map((doc)=>
     doc.data()))
    );

Comment: @PriyanshuSuman No, the code highlighted in the error message. However, that collection will need to be purged too. Just deleting `/rooms/someId` **will not** also delete the collection `/rooms/someId/messages`.

Comment: Ok. So maybe the doc is deleted but the message section is still there which is creating ambiguity.?